# Rewrite ALL Firebase Cloud Functions to hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I would like to rewrite all of my cloud functions, or a subset under a specific name from my hosting.

I see (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) firebase supports single rewrites, and if I have had an express app encompesing all of my functions I could have done so, however, I don't.

I have 100-200 functions starting with `connect-`, for example `connect-facebook?some_param=1`, and I would like to rewrite all of them from:

`https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/api/connect-$0`

But I didn't see any way to capture the name and pass it along, I have to select a single function.

Is there a way to rewrite multiple functions pattern-like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do pattern rewrites in the Firebase Hosting to Cloud Functions integration. You will have to list out all functions explicitly.

It should be possible to generate the relevant JSON from the patterns, and then include this generated output in your `firebase.json`.

Comment: Thanks. Before I close this, do you know if there is any way then to add a domain for cloud functions like I can for hosting? Such that there will be an "api.mysite.com" which is just a mask for cloud functions

Comment: Any domain mapping you have for Firebase Hosting automatically also applies to the Cloud Functions you rewrite in that hosting project. So your `https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/api/connect-facebook` will also be available on `https://example.com/api/connect-facebook`.